# jOOQ bad SQL grammar for new H2

Tags: jooq

I just updated to Spring Boot 2.7.2 and the new H2 2.1.214.

The jOOQ version is 3.16.6 (pro).

Since then, I get a bad grammar SQL exception with a limit query.

If I understand it correctly, the keyword `limit` is no longer supported in H2 - instead, `FETCH FIRST` should be used.

```
dslContext.select( FOO.fields() ).from( FOO ).limit( 1 )

select "FOO".ID" from "FOO" limit ?
```

Stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "select ""FOO"".""ID"" from ""FOO"" limit [*]?"; SQL statement:
select "FOO"."ID" from "FOO" limit ? [42000-214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:502)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:223)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:199)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:247)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getSyntaxError(Parser.java:898)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:572)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareLocal(SessionLocal.java:631)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareCommand(SessionLocal.java:554)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1116)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:92)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:288)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:337)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor287.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at net.ttddyy.dsproxy.proxy.ConnectionProxyLogic.performQueryExecutionListener(ConnectionProxyLogic.java:112)
    at net.ttddyy.dsproxy.proxy.ConnectionProxyLogic.access$000(ConnectionProxyLogic.java:25)
    at net.ttddyy.dsproxy.proxy.ConnectionProxyLogic$1.execute(ConnectionProxyLogic.java:50)
    at net.ttddyy.dsproxy.listener.MethodExecutionListenerUtils.invoke(MethodExecutionListenerUtils.java:42)
    at net.ttddyy.dsproxy.proxy.ConnectionProxyLogic.invoke(ConnectionProxyLogic.java:47)
    at net.ttddyy.dsproxy.proxy.jdk.ConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(ConnectionInvocationHandler.java:25)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy140.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor287.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at net.ttddyy.dsproxy.proxy.ConnectionProxyLogic.performQueryExecutionListener(ConnectionProxyLogic.java:112)
    at net.ttddyy.dsproxy.proxy.ConnectionProxyLogic.access$000(ConnectionProxyLogic.java:25)
    at net.ttddyy.dsproxy.proxy.ConnectionProxyLogic$1.execute(ConnectionProxyLogic.java:50)
    at net.ttddyy.dsproxy.listener.MethodExecutionListenerUtils.invoke(MethodExecutionListenerUtils.java:42)
    at net.ttddyy.dsproxy.proxy.ConnectionProxyLogic.invoke(ConnectionProxyLogic.java:47)
    at net.ttddyy.dsproxy.proxy.jdk.ConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(ConnectionInvocationHandler.java:25)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy140.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.quickperf.sql.connection.QuickPerfDatabaseConnection.prepareStatement(QuickPerfDatabaseConnection.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor287.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:238)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy320.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.jooq.impl.ProviderEnabledConnection.prepareStatement(ProviderEnabledConnection.java:109)
    at org.jooq.impl.SettingsEnabledConnection.prepareStatement(SettingsEnabledConnection.java:82)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.prepare(AbstractResultQuery.java:210)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:307)
    ... 92 more
```

1. Is this a known issue?
2. Is there a way to rewrite the query?

Comment: There seems to be a typo in your H2 version. Is it 2.1.214? Can you please post your configuration? What exact `SQLDialect` are you using? I'm not aware of H2 having removed `LIMIT` support, so something else must be the problem. What is the exception stack trace?

Comment: Are you using H2 with some specific compatibility mode?

Comment: You are correct was a typo in the version.

I had the same issue with eclipse link looks like the 'limit' is gone. If i change the limit with offset and fetch result is working.

See https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/eclipselink/issues/1579 and 
https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/eclipselink/issues/1393

I will add the complete error message and stacktrace

Comment: Tried it with OFFSET and FETCH FIRST, this worked

Comment: H2 has a track record of introducing huge breaking changes in patch releases, but I'm not aware of this one (despite, indeed, `LIMIT` no longer being documented!). All our integration tests pass...

Comment: Sorry saw our question right now.
We are using MODE=MSSQLServer. Do you also test this in your integration tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a frequent misconception about how to use jOOQ with H2 as a test database, so [I've written a blog post about jOOQ's stance on this](https://blog.jooq.org/using-h2-as-a-test-database-product/). The feature was also requested on the jOOQ issue tracker as [#13895](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13895)

**TL;DR:** With jOOQ, please don't use H2's compatibility modes.

#### Valid configurations

There is only really 1 valid configuration when using H2 as a test database product for a different production database product:

- Use jOOQ's `SQLDialect.H2` and H2 native, without compatibility mode. This is integration tested by jOOQ.

You might be tempted to:

- Use jOOQ's `SQLDialect.SQLSERVER` and H2 with SQL Server compatibility mode. This is **not** integration tested by jOOQ (see details below). I don't recommend doing this, because it is likely you'll run into a limitation of H2's compatibility mode that jOOQ assumes is there, because jOOQ thinks it's an actual SQL Server instance.
- Use `SQLDialect.H2` with H2 in compatibility mode doesn't really make sense, because, well, `LIMIT` is valid in H2, but not in SQL Server, which supports only `TOP` or `OFFSET .. FETCH`. So you're not going to get a good SQL dialect match. See e.g.: https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/3537

#### Some background on compatibility modes and using H2 as a test DB

The assumption in jOOQ is when you use H2, then you use H2 natively (e.g. as an in-memory database, also in production). Using H2 as a simple test database isn't the primary use-case for H2, even if it has seen a lot of popularity in recent years. But why not just use a [testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/) based approach instead, and develop / integration test only with your production RDBMS? The benefits are obvious:

- You don't have any such infrastructure problems and test artifacts
- You get to use *all* the vendor specific features, among which table valued functions, table valued parameters, XML/JSON, etc.

The H2 compatibility modes are to make sure your native SQL Server queries work on H2 without any changes. This is useful for purely JDBC based applications. But since you're using jOOQ, and `SQLDialect.H2`, why keep a compatibility mode around in H2? jOOQ already handles the translation between dialects, if you want to continue using H2 as a test database product. But again, I think your life will be simpler if you're using testcontainers. [You can even use it to generate jOOQ code as shown here](https://blog.jooq.org/using-testcontainers-to-generate-jooq-code/).

Comment: So jooq does not evaluate the H2 mode and sets the dialect correctly. So I should just overwrite it manually, correct?

Testcontainers are on the top of backlog ;)

Comment: @MelleD: Yes, you should override it manually.

Comment: Ok fair enough make sense, thanks.

Comment: @MelleD: I think it might be worth logging a warning when we detect unsupported combinations of SQL dialect and H2 compatibility mode. Might be useful for others: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13892

Comment: I set the grammer to SQLDialect.SQLSERVER. My issue is now that H2 NOT supports everything from the SQL_SERVER like "SET IDENTITY_INSERT ".


Now i cannot different in code with die dialect if the runtime is using H2 or SQL_SERVER. Before it was easy with 'if ( getDslContext().dialect().equals( SQLDialect.SQLSERVER ) )'

Do you think it make sense to create a dialect for every H2 Mode?
Like SQLDialect.H2_SQLSERVER. Then we have the chance to different in our codebase which env is set.

What do you think?

Comment: @MelleD: You picked the approach that is **not** integration tested. I recommended you use `SQLDialect.H2` when running queries on H2, and stop using the H2 compatibility mode. But even better, use testcontainers, and run everything on SQL Server. jOOQ will not support the H2 compatibility modes. The problems you're seeing are all unnecessary if you were not using H2 as a test database. The use-case no longer makes sense since testcontainers (and docker)

Comment: @MelleD: To be clear: The clean, long term solution is to use testcontainers. The quick fix is to use `SQLDialect.H2` with H2 in native mode, not a compatibility mode. But you will *still* run into limitations whenever you're trying to use a T-SQL feature that jOOQ cannot emulate in H2

Comment: Currently i use H2 mode SQL_SERVER with SQLDialect.SQL_SERVER. Works so far nice. Just the issue hat H2 not supports the 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT '. In H2 is no different for identify inserts. This is very special for SQL_SERVER.

Comment: @MelleD: If you *want* to continue using this approach, then I recommend you request a feature from H2 to support these `SET` commands: https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/new

Comment: I can try that, but maybe it make also sense to have a chance to seperate this on jOOQ Dialect Level :)

Comment: @MelleD: No, that doesn't make sense, I'm sorry. We have 30 dialects to support already. These compatibility modes are not very well documented, have changed incompatibly in the past, and are strategically a dead end in the long run, since testcontainers and docker have been a thing. Besides, the first suggestion I made (using `SQLDialect.H2` with H2 native) also works well (have you tried that?). Moreover, H2 has caused a lot of headaches in the recent past with incompatible changes between 1.4 and 2.0. I don't see jOOQ investing time in supporting their compatibility modes.

Comment: @MelleD: You've noticed it yourself. Your upgrade broke your tests, probably because of this regression: https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/3537. H2 changes such things all the time, sometimes between patch releases. For jOOQ's maintenance, it would be a nightmare, and a ton of busywork, for only very little value compared to the main alternatives, which are 1) Using H2 natively without compatibility mode 2) Testing your application directly on SQL Server.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. It would only be useful to extend the enum, internally the H2_SQL_SERVER dialect could use the normal SQL_SERVER dialect.

Comment: @MelleD: I understood you perfectly. I just disagree that this is a useful feature to add. You're underestimating the effort of such a change in jOOQ, and overestimate the value it would provide you.

Comment: But that's another topic about the effort.

For me, the value is just being able to differentiate my env. And from the dialect there is a difference between H2 Mode SQL Server and SQL_SERVER.
From my point of view the Enum dialect should also represent that.

The fact that the dialect does not support everything afterwards, especially with H2 mode, makes total sense and I would see it that way. But it's great to document and implement. The H2 Mode Sql Server is the same as the SQL Server.
The H2 Mode Oracle is the same dialect as the Oracle etc.

Maybe discussion is better on github

Comment: @MelleD: You can try your luck here with some details explaining why you think this would add value to you: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new/choose. I will still very likely disagree, but indeed, github issues are a better discussion channel :)